# Webpack missing fields on browser window global

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Very simple react loader

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'static/js/');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'js');

var config = {
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?/,
                include: APP_DIR,
                loader: 'babel'
            },
        ]
    },
    entry: APP_DIR + '/app.jsx',
    output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        filename: 'app.js'
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Then I serve the result using something like the below. It sets some global variables passed from a golang backend, and then loads the bundle.

```
<script type="text/babel">
    window.AuthURL = "{{.AuthURL}}";
    window.CODE = GetCode("code");
    window.APPVERSION = '{{.VERSION }}';
</script>
<script src="static/js/app.js"></script>
```

app.jsx looks like

```
console.log(window);
console.log(window.Infinity);
console.log(window.APPVERSION);
```

I get something like this on the console

[image: proof]

The variables I set show highlighted on the browser, but not visible to webpack. What am I doing wrong? Can I achive the desired bahaviour?

[image]

Comment: For that "text/babel" script, did you load Babel through CDN to make sure it get transpiled and executed?

Comment: @Ming I just got this a couple of minutes ago. The transpiler works great, but I dont want to use it anymore. Ended up forgetting to remove this type attribute after implementing webpack. Removing it makes it all work as expected